# unique_ptr: what is the effect of calling reset before assignment

Tags: c++, c++14, reset, unique-ptr

In c++14, what is the difference between assigning to an existing unique_ptr:

```
    std::unique_ptr<double> p = std::make_unique<double>(1.0);
    p = std::make_unique<double>(2.0);
```

and first calling reset before assigning to it:?

```cpp
    std::unique_ptr<double> p = std::make_unique<double>(1.0);
    p.reset();
    p = std::make_unique<double>(2.0);
```

I thought adding `.reset()` before assignment will have not a big impact on the code, but the one without `reset()` seems to produce different (and more) assembly code when compiled with `-O3`. Check the code online here:

https://godbolt.org/z/mBApWH

https://godbolt.org/z/JfStmC

Comment: What do you mean by saying 'equivalent' ? At second version, you reset the ptr twice, at first version, just once so it is normal to produce different assembly code.

Comment: Why would you ever do the second? At best it's equivalent in performance, but could also be worse, not to mention it worse overall readability.

Comment: One page two compilers both versions [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/VPV_un).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe most of the differences between compiler output are due to the fact that for one of the two snippets it was able to optimize more stuff out. After all, you just add a couple of constants to a variable. If we're to make optimizer's job a bit more difficult, outputs are [nearly identical](https://godbolt.org/z/HBB6Zv). There compiler has no idea how `foo` works and has to produce both calls to it and add results to `x`, no room to be clever.

To answer you question, the difference is small. Move-assignment operator of `unique_ptr` frees memory anyway, so calling `reset` before it is redundant. But, as evident from my link, compiler may omit that operation if it knows that the pointer was reset.

However, calling `reset` before may be useful if memory held by the pointer will be freed before allocation of new memory, thus reducing memory footprint of the program.

Comment: nice example, thanks. I think that calling `reset` first is not entirely redundant though, as it does change the order of operations: the memory for the first double is freed before the memory for the second is allocated.

Answer (score 3):

There seems to be an opportunity for improvement in the GCC optimizer.

In the second version we get

```
        call    operator new(unsigned long)
        mov     QWORD PTR [r12], 0                     ; [r12] is 0
        mov     esi, 4
        mov     rdi, rax
        call    operator delete(void*, unsigned long)
        mov     edi, 4
        call    operator new(unsigned long)
        mov     rdi, QWORD PTR [r12]                   ; rdi=[r12] == 0 (duh)
        mov     DWORD PTR [rax], 1111
        mov     QWORD PTR [r12], rax
        test    rdi, rdi                               ; unnecesary test
        je      .L1                                    ; branch always taken
        mov     esi, 4                                 ; unreachable code
        call    operator delete(void*, unsigned long)  ;
.L1:
```

**clang 9** on the other hand, produces [much smaller code](https://godbolt.org/z/FHMwkv) for the second version because it is able to eliminate the first `new`/`delete`.

```
        push    rbx
        mov     rbx, rdi
        mov     qword ptr [rdi], 0
        mov     edi, 4
        call    operator new(unsigned long)
        mov     dword ptr [rax], 1111
        mov     qword ptr [rbx], rax
        mov     rax, rbx
        pop     rbx
        ret
```